# Formula for overdetermined logical matrix pseudoinverse not requiring SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, svd

In https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:YI_%3D_PI.png, you will find a formula-based solution for an overdetermined logical matrix pseudoinverse. This simple formula gives the same result as the Moore-Penrose method. Does anyone know of any other overdetermined logical matrices that can be solved without using SVD methods?

Comment: Your question is more likely to get an answer if it includes an example written here in proper mathematical notation, rather than as code in a language not everyone knows, with undefined variables in it, obfuscated behind an image and a link.

Comment: Anyhow, you know that there is a closed formula for inverses of full-rank matrices that does not require the SVD, right? $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ or $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$, depending on the dimensions.

Comment: I am sorry about the Mathematica jargon.  I have no idea how to use proper mathematical notation for computation where I use Tuples and Partition.

Comment: Thank you for your additional comment.  For a=4, w=3, the matrix is 64x12 and it will reduce in rank to 10.  With row reduction, the matrix is neither logical or binary.

Comment: It is very clear that I need a coauthor.  I am doug@youvan.com .  Retired, I no longer have access to graduate students and postdocs as in the past at MIT.

Comment: As you can see from the attached image, I have the "proof" down to 4 lines of Mathematica code.  The 3rd line needs to be transcribed into a line of code.  MatLab should be very similar.

Comment: I've also posted here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375744/formula-for-overdetermined-logical-matrix-pseudoinverse-not-requiring-svd .

Comment: Here is a question to the Wolfram Community concerning notation: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2109572?p_p_auth=ydsnorN7